# Divide arc in pieces of equal length

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have an object described by the parametric equations $x = x\left(t\right)$ and $y = y\left(t\right)$. I want to divide the arc into $n$ pieces of equal length.

I know that the arc-length is defined by
$$l =\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(x\left(t\right)'\right)^2+\left(y\left(t\right)'\right)^2 }\cdot dt.$$
I know that I need, for the $i$-th sub-arc, to solve the equation
$$ l_i=\frac{i}{n}l \overset{!}{=}\int_{0}^{t_i}\sqrt{\left(x\left(t\right)'\right)^2+\left(y\left(t\right)'\right)^2 }\cdot dt $$
for $t_i$.

However, the integral is of a form that, in general, can only be evaluated numerically.

Is there any way to solve for $t_i$ without knowing the analytic result of the integration?

Comment: It would strongly help your cause to post what your $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are

Comment: They are both continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve for it analytically, but you are well set up for numerical root finding.  Given a $t$ you can compute the arc length up to $t$ and the derivative of the arc length with respect to $t$ is $\sqrt{\left(x\left(t\right)'\right)^2+\left(y\left(t\right)'\right)^2 }$ which you already know how to calculate.  This is perfect for Newton's method.

Comment: But what would be a suited initial guess for the approximation?

Comment: Absent better info, I would start with $\frac {2\pi}n$